# Result of fold operation on empty range

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I am writing [library](http://volnitsky.com/project/ro/) which allows some function programming operations on ranges. Ranges are generalization of STL containers. My question is what result of folding for empty range should be?

```
auto r  = range(4);    // lazy numeric range {0,1,2,3}
auto r0 = range(0);    // empty range {}
vector<string> vs  {"a", "bb"};
vector<string> vs0 {};

// this is obvious and implemented part    

cout <<  (r  || add);  // 6,  || - folding op
cout <<  (r0 || add);  // 0
cout <<  (vs || add);  // "abb"
cout <<  (vs0|| add);  // ""

cout <<  (r  || mul);  // 0
cout <<  (r0 || mul);  // 1

cout <<  (r  || max);  // 3

//  What result of these should be?

cout <<  (r0 || div);   // ???
cout <<  (r0 || sub);   // ???
cout <<  (r0 || max);   // -∞ ???
cout <<  (r0 || min);   // +∞ ???
cout <<  (r0 || ???);   // result of arbitrary op?
```

**EDIT - ANSWER**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element

Comment: Usually the `fold` function is defined with 3 arguments: the list to fold over, the function to apply and the starting value of the accumulator. The return value of folding the empty list would then naturally be the starting value that was given as the argument.

Comment: Also I just want to say that I think it's a bad idea to overload `||` to be a folding operator.

Comment: I know  about `std::accumulate` and how initial value should be specified.  My question in about what this value should be for certain ops.  Goal of the project not to please everyone.  It is suited only for some narrow audience (C++ oneliners, CodeJams, etc).

Comment: Why not let caller to specify initial value explicitly?

Comment: @Lol4t0 - because fold in my library is operation, not the function. And operator have only two arguments: range and folding functor.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky, but `fold` _usually_ takes 3 arguments, if empty list are allowed. It has no sense on empty list without explicitly passed initial value at all. If you get empty range and you didn't pass initial value, you should return _nothing_. Throw an exception, may be. Otherwise you should use 1st/last element of the range as initial value

Comment: Might I suggest implementing named infix operators for this, rather than overriding other operators in possibly confusing ways?  Ie, `myVec *fold* sum` style syntax, rather than `myVec || sum`.  (And yes, this involves overriding operators in strange ways, but is less confusing)

Comment: @Yakk - I know about this method.  Maybe in future.  This is more readable, but adds complexity and a little bit verbosity.

Comment: @Yakk Off-topic, but I'm really curious - how would you do that in C++?

Comment: @Reuben `template<typename BinOp> struct NamedOperator { BinOp op; } template<typename BinOp, typename T> struct LeftForm { BinOp op; T lhs; LeftForm(T a, BinOp b):op(b),lhs(a) {}}; template<typename BinOp, typename T> LeftForm<BinOp,T> operator*( T left, NamedOperator<BinOp> nop ) { return LeftForm<BinOp,T>(left, nop.op); } template<typename BinOp, typename T, typename U> auto operator*(LeftForm<BinOp,T> left, U rhs)->decltype(left.op(left.lhs,rhs)) {return left.op(left.lhs,rhs);}` easily? Harder is making the syntax to make `+sum+` & `*mul*` etc operators cleanly. Code is semi-speudo-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your "folders" are instances of some template, with a binary function attached and maybe an initial value.

Traditionally, fold is defined as recursively calling said binary function on (initial, first), then (old value, next) until you run out of stuff to call it on.

There is no such initial value such that subtraction and division work the way you might expect them to (such that fold({1,2}) is 1/2).

Thus "folders" of subtraction and division are either "sums of inverse" and "product of inverse" (ie, fold(r) = 1/fold(r), and fold(r) = -fold(r), which seems pretty boring), or they are fundamentally different things that don't work on empty containers.

max and min should clearly generate the highest and lowest value for a given type, or be the folders of the second type that do not make sense on empty containers.

By "not work", they could throw an exception, or they could return something like a `boost::optional<T>` -- ie, on an empty list, they do not return anything.

Your folder type could take a function which finds the initial value for a given type, which should resolve to a traits template class or a free function (similar to `std::begin`).

...

Edit: from the comments below, an improvement to the answer.

The real trick here is that there is no left-hand identity for subtraction and division  But there is a right hand identity!

Operations that only have a right hand identity should be expressed as right-hand folds, and operations that only have a left hand identity should be expressed as left-hand folds (aka, foldr and foldl)

Ie, the natural way to express a fold on a list `{a,b,c}` with identity `id` of binary operation `*op*` is:

```
( (id *op* a) *op* b ) *op c
```

but for operations without a left-hand identity, this doesn't work.

However, if you reverse the fold handedness, you get this:

```
a *op* (b *op* (c *op* id))
```

which works so long as you have a right-hand identity.

This is important for `div` and `sub` -- `div` has a right-hand identity of 1, and `sub` has a right-hand identity of 0, but neither has a left-hand identity.  (there is no element `e` such that `e-x = x` for all `x`.  There is an element `e` such that `x-e = x` for all `x`, namely 0).

The same is true of exponentiation (which has a right-hand identity of `1`, but no left-hand identity).

This still doesn't match what a naive expectation of what `fold div` should do.  It works on lists of length 2, but on lists of length 3 something unintuitive happens.  But at least it is mathematically sound.  :)

Comment: You assumption is correct - folder is templated functor with trait method `fold_init_value()`.   After replacing definition of folding (in my head) from `R0+R1+R2 ...`  to `init+R0+R1...`, it became clear what value should be for empty ranges for `div` and `sub`  (1 and 0).  Thanks.

Comment: @leonid Note that this makes div and sub boring.  They only differ from add and mult a separable way (ie, applying a uniform per element transformation to the sequence, then add or mult, gives the same result).  Errors happen, you need a way to propagate them, so you might want to work out a mechanism?

Comment: I do not understand - `boring`, `separable way`.  Is this something from abstract algebra?  Unfortunately, I don't know it.  BTW, I found the answer -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky -- "boring" as in "not interesting".  "separable" -- an operation on N inputs is "separable" with respect to a second operation if it can be expressed as a unary operation on each of the N inputs, followed by the second operation.  Note that both `div` and `sub` have no *left hand side* identity element -- there is no element `e` such that `e-x = x` for all `x`, and similarly for `e/x = x`.  Meanwhile, there is an element `e` such that `e+x=x` for all `x` (namely 0), and there is a different element `e` such that `e*x=x` for all `x`.  But this does give me an idea!